# Error when loading Models to Controller CakePHP 1.3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I load 2 Models into my Controller.

```
var $uses = array( 'Territoryset', 'Users.User' );
```

I call a function from the model

```
$users = $this->User->getUsersList();
```

I had an error:

> **pg_query() [function.pg-query]: Query failed: ERROR:  syntax error at or near getUsersList**

I changed the order of the $uses

```
var $uses = array('Users.User', 'Territoryset');
```

And then I didn't get any error. I can't really explain why the order of calling makes a difference?

Comment: It's a legacy code that I've been asked to fix, otherwise I wouldn't work on 1.3

Comment: Indeed there is a relation of BelongsTo in territoryset.  
 
    var $belongsTo = array(  
  'User' => array(
   'className' => 'User',
   'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
   'conditions' => '',
   'fields' => '',
   'order' => ''
  ),

Answer (score 3):

### There's a missing plugin prefix

> Indeed there is a relation of BelongsTo in territoryset.
>
> ```
> var $belongsTo = array(   
>     'User' => array( 
>         'className' => 'User', # <- no plugin prefix
>         ...
> ```

See [the docs regarding loading plugin models](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Plugins.html#plugin-models) for some background info.

This model definition will cause, by act of loading the belongsTo association definition, both of the following code examples to return an instance of the model `model/user.php` if it exists or `AppModel` if it does not:

```
$x = ClassRegistry::init('User'); 
$x = ClassRegistry::init('Users.User');
```

In essence this is due to the limitation of not having namespaces in php4 - it's not possible to load two classes with the same name, so the first class loaded with a given name wins.

When *first* using the alias `'Users.User'` to refer to the User model, the class in the file `plugins/users/model/user.php` will be loaded (if it exists) and then an instance of *this* class will be returned for both of these code examples:

```
$x = ClassRegistry::init('User'); 
$x = ClassRegistry::init('Users.User');
```

Hence the reason the order of the `uses` models has an effect, is because it determines whether `User` or `Users.User` (due to the missing plugin prefix in the territoryset model) is the first reference to this model name, and therefore which object populates the class registry , and which object is returned for all later references to the `User` or `*.User`.

Comment: I got the problem, though even after changing the class in $belongsTo didn't solve the order problem, but now I mange to use $this->Territoryset->User->getUsersList(); after I changed the className to 'Users.User'

Comment: I don't know what the start of your comment means - but the thing you changed is what I was suggesting you edit.

Comment: Sorry the problem persist with var $uses ... and $this->User but works fine $this->Territoryset->User->getUsersList(); Thanks for the help.

Comment: I still don't really know what you mean but if anything doesn't work there's more bad code than is in the question.